# VSTS build error MC3074 'Interaction.Triggers' does not exist

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am getting the following error when attempting to build a WPF application on VSTS using Hosted VS2017 build agent:

> Modules\ManualOperation\ManualOperationDialog.xaml(61):Modules\ManualOperation\ManualOperationDialog.xaml(61,22):
>   Error MC3074: The tag 'Interaction.Triggers' does not exist in XML
>   namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity'. Line 61
>   Position 22.

The same project builds with no errors in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.1. There have also been no changes to this project since it was last built by VSTS.

Project specifics:

1. .NET Framework 4.6.1
2. References System.Windows.Interactivity version 4.5.0

The System.Windows.Interactivity properties are:
[image]

We have a very basic build set up on VSTS. This is very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The reference System.Windows.Interactivity which you referred locally, please remove it and add the nuget package Expression.Blend.Sdk https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/ instead and try again. Note: before VS Build task, please add a NuGet retsore task.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I would mark your comment as the answer if I could.

Comment: I added it as an answer, you can mark it now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Hosted VS2017 agent, which means the reference System.Windows.Interactivity from local machine can not be reccongnized.

So you can remove the local reference and add **[Expression.Blend.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/) nuget package** (which contains the wpf 4.5) instead.

**Note:** before VS Build task, you need to add a **NuGet restore** task to download the nuget package.